# SystemVerilog Assertion for valid (request) - ack checking?

Tags: system-verilog, verification, system-verilog-assertions

I am studying SystemVerilog Assertion. I applied SVA to check valid-ack spec. Spec is as below:

> When the valid is drived (0 to 1), the valid should be equal to 1
>   until the ack is drived (1). When the ack is de-asserted (1 to 0), the
>   valid is also de-asserted (1 to 0).

To check this spec, I wrote two property (pr1 and pr2). You can see the SVA code from the below link.
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5gHd

I expected that two property works exactly same. However, pr2 does not work as I expected (I expected that the assertion might fail at 50ns since the valid is equal to 1 but ack is equal to 0 at the 50ns).

**Waveform:** https://www.edaplayground.com/w/x/u5

What is the wrong at the pr2 (at 50ns)?

Best regards,

Comment: `pr1` appears correct at first glance.  The first post-condition in `pr2` will match as long as `valid` is asserted, regardless of what `ack` is doing.  That is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the SystemVerilog LRM:

> A repetition with a range of min minimum and max maximum number of iterations can be expressed with the
>   consecutive repetition operator [* min:max].

In pr2 you have used repetition operator with max equal to `$`  which stands for finite, but unbounded number of iterations so sequence`valid[*1:$]` will last as long as `valid` is asserted and `ack` will be checked only after `valid` goes down.